# Evaluation of the preprocessing to make a dataset anonymous

Tags: python, nlp, anonymization

I have a very huge dataset from the NLP area and I want to make it anonymous. Is there any way to check if my pre-processing is correct? Generaly, is there any way to evaluate how good is the pre-processing for the anonyminity?

I want to mention that the dataset is really huge, therefore it can be cheched manually.

Comment: There's no other way than checking manually, and it's rare that a dataset is perfectly anonymized. For the problem of size you can check a random subset of the data.